# Do I still need to determine backgroundRefreshStatus before using region monitoring under iOS8

Tags: ios8, cllocationmanager

Under iOS7 I had to check `locationManager:authorizationStatus` and `UIApplication:backgroundRefreshStatus` before relying on region monitoring. The app had to be authorized, in Settings, for both.

Under iOS8 locationManager has `locationManager:requestAlwaysAuthorization` which allows background processing for region monitoring.

Under iOS8 apps that only use location services don't appear under Background App Refresh in settings.

All this makes me think I no longer need to check `UIApplication:backgroundRefreshStatus` but the (pre-release) docs say the following for `UIApplication:backgroundRefreshStatus`:

> This property reflects whether the app can be launched into the
>   background to handle background behaviors, such as processing
>   background location updates and performing background fetches. If your
>   app relies on being launched into the background to perform tasks, you
>   can use the value of this property to determine if doing so is
>   possible and to warn the user if it is not

Does anyone know the correct approach?